# setTimeout - Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, settimeout

I try to make a setTimeout on IE9 but it still throwing a "Invalid argument" Exception...

Here is my code :

```
var timeout;
timeout = setTimeout((function(s_text){
    alert(s_text);
})('Hello'), 1000);
```

Does anyone has a clue ?

Comment: why you are passing `'Hello'`? Remove that

Comment: `setTimeout` ultimately needs a function *(or a string, but forget that)*, so if you immediately invoke the function, you're not actually passing it to `setTimeout`; you're passing its return value. So if you want to do that, you'd need to return a function that does what you want. `return function() { alert(s_text) }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The approach you are implementing is not going to work.  You are using an IIFE that will execute immediately:

```
(function(s_text){
    alert(s_text);
})('Hello')
```

And 'Hello' will be alerted.  But then, since that method doesn't return anything, then you are calling the timeout with nothing.

```
timeout = setTimeout(/*undefined or null*/, 1000);
```

So that's the issue.

edit:
If you want to use a variable that already exists outside of the scope, as long as it is defined in a parent scope that the function can see you can use it directly:

```
var timeout;
var alert_text = "hello";
timeout = setTimeout(function(){
    alert(alert_text);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: I understand what you're saying. But then, how do you call a function in wich you need to use a variable outside its scope ? (that's why I pass 'Hello' as parameter to my function)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I seem to recall that I had this problem before but it looks like I was in error...